# Is there a way to query mySql if my connection has started a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have found many anwsers of how frameworks handle transaction nesting, but I couldn't found if there is an executable query against mySql RDMS that returns if a transaction has started or not. Is it posible? thanks

Comment: `show full processlist;` may help somehow.

Comment: @Igor nop, I do: show full processlist;
START TRANSACTION;
show full processlist;
and nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit tricky, but you can find an example how to do this at http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=145

Answer (score 0):

I am copying here @wonk0 link as it is no more aviable.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `myexample` (
  OUT errno    INT,
  OUT error    VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE need_to_commit BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

  main:BEGIN

    -- for example, catch duplicate key errors and roll back
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT myexample;
      SET errno = 1060,
          error = 'Duplicate key.';
    END;

    -- catch any other errors that should cause automatic rollbacks

    -- ------
    -- set up the savepoint / trx handler
    -- 

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1305
    BEGIN
      START TRANSACTION;
      SET need_to_commit = TRUE;
    END;

    -- this will have no effect if we are not in a trx
    SAVEPOINT myexample;

    -- this will error if we are not in a trx, be caught above, and start a trx
    -- it will do nothing if we are already in a trx
    RELEASE SAVEPOINT myexample;

    -- this will always set a savepoint
    -- because we are now guaranteed to be in a trx
    SAVEPOINT myexample;

    -- 
    -- done setting up savepoint / trx
    -- ------

    -- initialize the OUT parameters
    SET errno = 0,
        error = '';

    -- do some stuff
    INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (2);

    -- you can even handle your own errors (without handlers!)
    IF ( 0 != 1 ) THEN
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT myexample;
      SET errno = 1234,
          error = 'Zero is not one!';
      LEAVE main;
    END IF;

  END; -- main

  -- if we were not in a transaction to start with
  -- we should not leave one dangling, so commit here
  IF need_to_commit THEN 
    COMMIT;
  END IF;

END $$


DELIMITER ;



/*

EXAMPLE

mysql> create table mytable (a int primary key) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> create table yourtable (b int primary key) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> call myexample(@e,@r); select @e,@r;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+------+------------------+
| @e   | @r               |
+------+------------------+
| 1234 | Zero is not one! |
+------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable union select * from yourtable;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into yourtable values (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call myexample(@e,@r); select @e,@r;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+------+----------------+
| @e   | @r             |
+------+----------------+
| 1060 | Duplicate key. |
+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable union select * from yourtable;
+---+
| a |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

*/
```